# Does chmod 700 hides directory from other users or just restrict them to display files inside the directory?

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, chmod

My home directory contains 'project' as a directory which contains 'confidential' as sub-directory and 'confidential' contains some files.

I just want that only I can access this folder and other users can't access it.

I ran command

```
Me:~ me$ chmod -R 700 project/confidential
```

`Me:~ me$ su Bob`

`bob:/home/me/project$ ls`

```
code confidential
```

Here it displays two folders to Bob, but Bob can't access confidential files if he tries to list them.

So, Does chmod not hide the folder from other users? I want other users to access only 'code' directory not confidential, how can I hide it?

Comment: You can't if you want other users to be able to access the `code` directory. The parent directory (`/home/me/project/`) obviously needs read and execute permission to other users, for them to be able to access the `code` directory. For this reason they can find out that another directory (called `confidential`) is present too. To completely hide the directory `confidential`, you can put it into another sub-directory (say `/home/me/project/etc/`) and give `700` permission to it (the `etc` directory). This way the users will see the `etc`, but not the `confidential` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current directory tree is something like:

```
/home/me/project/
/home/me/project/code/
/home/me/project/confidential/
```

You cannot hide the `confidential` directory, if you want other users to be able to find out and access any directory besides `confidential`. The parent directory (`/home/me/project/`) obviously needs read and execute permission to other users, for them to be able to list the contents of the `project` directory and find out that a directory named `code` exits. For this reason they can find out that another directory (called `confidential`) is present besides the `code` directory.

---

To completely hide the directory `confidential`, you can put it into another sub-directory (say `/home/me/project/etc/`) and give 700 permission to it (the `etc` directory). This way, the other users will see the `etc` directory, but will not be able to change into it or list it (or any of its sub-directories). So the `confidential` directory will be completely hidden.

---

Another option may be this:

```
chmod 711 /home/me/project/
chmod 700 /home/me/project/confidential/
```

This way, you prevent other users to read the contents of the `project` directory: `ls -l /home/me/project/` will give `Permission denied` error. But, they will be able the change to the `project` directory or any other sub-directory **they know it exists** and list it: `ls /home/me/project/code` will work, provided the `code` directory has the "normal" (755) permissions.

However, in this configuration, note that the outputs of the following commands the other users may be able to run:

```
$ ls /home/me/project/confidential
ls: cannot open directory '/home/me/project/confidential': Permission denied
$ ls /home/me/project/other
ls: cannot access '/home/me/project/other': No such file or directory
```

So, even this solution may not be perfect, because the other users may be able to determine the name of the hidden directory *by trial and error*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Much appreciated :)